# C# ThreadPool that passes function as parameter

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-2.0

I am using C# 2, which is default in Unity3d.

How can I turn this.

```
WaitCallback callback = new WaitCallback (state => Fibo((int)state));
int data = 40000000;

BGThreadPool.Instance.QueueUserWorkItem (callback, data);
```

Into this

```
BGThreadPool.Instance.QueueUserWorkItem (Fibo (40000000));
```

My queueWorkItem function

```
public void QueueUserWorkItem (WaitCallback callBack, System.Object arg) {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem (callBack, arg);
}
```

Comment: Unity is completely single-threaded and does not use threads in any way. I'm wondering are you using one of the common helper-scripts for putting calculation threads on the background?  Regarding `MonoBehavior` and `Component` you can't put them on another thread at all, generally

Comment: Just for anyone googling here this article has a few introductory comments on threading in Unity http://nyahoon.com/blog-en/366

Comment: And FWIW this QA has basically everything you need to know about threading in Unity: http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/357040/view.html